# Creating mock for Document Client

Tags: moq, azure-cosmosdb, xunit

I am writing unit tests using xUnit and Moq. My class under test has a property

```
public DocumentClient documentClient {get; set;}
```

I am trying to mock this property using Moq and trying to mock OpenAsync method of DocumentClient. This is how I am creating the Mock object.

`var documentClientObj = new Mock<DocumentClient>();`

But I am getting an error saying "System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class"

Comment: The problem is that `DocumentClient` is `sealed` class. That is strictly forbidden in the moq. You could extract required functionality as an `interface` and then try to mock it...

Comment: But I need the DocumentClient type itself as I am using it later to create BulkExecutor. I don't have a choice to use the IDocumentClient interface.

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentClient` Is neither an abstract class nor an interface. This means that mocking libraries cannot create proxy implementations. If you stick with the class you can't mock it.

However the Cosmos DB library has the `IDocumentClient` interface in it which is what the `DocumentClient` class is implementing. You should switch to that and then you will be able to mock it.

Comment: But IDocumentClient does not have OpenAsync method in it.

Comment: What the `OpenAsync` method will do is just hit the database once to create the necessary internal cache and connections. Any call to the database should automatically generate the same cache in the `DocumentClient`. You can write your own `OpenAsync` method. All the `OpenAsync` method does is to loop through the ColletionFeedReader and just read the collection. Here is the [OpenAsync source](https://gist.github.com/Elfocrash/644d0817442c1e7812472493b562551c)

Comment: Also  I need the DocumentClient type itself as I am using it later to create BulkExecutor. I don't have a choice to use the IDocumentClient interface

Comment: @DevMJ You do actually. You can cast it whenever it needs to be used by the BulkExecutor. It's either that or no mocking at all. There is just no other way.